# Shuffling an array of items by the identifier connected to the buttons...Where am I going wrong?

Tags: arrays, swift, button, shuffle

Iv got an application that consists of 9 buttons and one label displaying the text that is associated with the fruit.

Iv created a struct with the name, the object and an identifier. I initially created an Outlet collection but couldn't figure out how to connect the buttons to the identifier variable that's initialised, then I made separate outlets for all.

The game runs perfectly from start to end - my problem now comes when I want to reply the game, I want the game to reset but shuffle the text label. So a new fruit name pops up every time the user presses replay.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? How will I be able to tap into the identifier and it shuffles the images when I click it.

Thank you

[image]

```
import Foundation

struct Fruitness
{
    var fruit = [Fruit]()
    
    var fruitOptions = [

        Fruit(identifier: 1, fruit:"", name: "KIWI"),
        Fruit(identifier: 2, fruit:"",name: "APPLE"),
        Fruit(identifier: 3, fruit:"", name: "PEAR"),
        Fruit(identifier: 4, fruit:"", name: "ORANGE"),
        Fruit(identifier: 5,fruit:"", name: "STRAWBERRY"),
        Fruit(identifier: 6,fruit:"", name: "WATERMELON"),
        Fruit(identifier: 7,fruit:"", name: "GRAPES"),
        Fruit(identifier: 8,fruit:"", name: "BANANA"),
        Fruit(identifier: 9,fruit:"", name: "CHERRY")
    ]
    
    var fruitIndex = [index]
    var fruitNumber = 0
    var score = 0
 

    mutating func checkAnswer(userAnswer: String) -> Bool {
        
        
        //Need to change answer to rightAnswer here.
        if userAnswer == fruitOptions[fruitNumber].fruit {
            score += 1 //We increase the value of score when we get the answer right.
            return true
        } else {
            return false
            
        }
    }
    
    func getScore() -> Int {
        return score
        
    }
    
    mutating func getFruitText() -> String {
    
        return fruitOptions[fruitNumber].name
         
        }
        
    
    
    func getProgress() -> Float {
        let progress = Float(fruitNumber) / Float(fruitOptions.count)
        return progress
        
        
    }
    
    mutating func nextFruit() {
        if fruitNumber + 1 < fruitOptions.count {
            
            fruitNumber += 1
            
        } else {
            
           // fruitNumber = 0
            score = 0
        }
    }
    
    mutating func shuffleFruitLabel(at index: Int) {
        fruitOptions.shuffle()
    }
    
    //TODO: Shuffle fruit on Buttons
    
    
    
}
```

contoller

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var fruitLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var playAgain: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton0: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton5: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton6: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton7: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionButton8: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet private var fruitButtons: [UIButton]!
    
    var fruitness = Fruitness()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        updateUI()
        
    }
    @IBAction func replayButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //  fruitLabel.text = fruitness.fruitOptions[randomFruit].name
        
        //self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        
    }
    @IBAction func touchButton(_ sender: UIButton)  {
        //--//
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle!
        let userGotItRight = fruitness.checkAnswer(userAnswer: userAnswer)
        
        if  userGotItRight {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        
        // fruitness.shuffleFruitTextWhenReset()
        fruitness.nextFruit()
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo:nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
        
        
        optionButton0.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton3.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton4.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton5.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton6.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton7.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        optionButton8.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        fruitLabel.text = fruitness.getFruitText()
        progressBar.progress = fruitness.getProgress()
        scoreLabel.text = "SCORE: \(fruitness.getScore())"
        
    }
}

func imageOnButton(fruit: String, on button: UIButton) {
    if button.currentTitle == fruit {
        button.setTitle(fruit, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

struct Fruit {

    var identifier: Int
    var name: String
    var fruit: String
    
  
    init(identifier : Int, fruit : String, name : String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.name = name
        self.fruit = fruit

    }

}
```

Comment: Please don’t put screenshots of code in your question. Copy and paste the code and use the code formatted to display it correctly. Thanks

Comment: Noted for next time mate, iv added the code.

Comment: thanks  just makes it easier for people to read and now will be indexed by StackOverflow for searches too. Also, it allows people to copy from your code to paste into their own answers to update it. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shuffle the fruitOptions array and re-assign the identifiers according to the new index.

For example:

```
fruitOptions.shuffle() // Shuffles the array

for (index, fruitOption) in fruitOptions.enumerated() {
      fruitOption.identifier = index + 1
}
```

Adding the (index, fruitOption) allows you to iterate through the array and access the index value of each item so you can assign that index value as the new identifier (+1 because I saw that you started the identifiers counting from 1 and not 0)

.enumerated just allows your to do what I have described above.
You can read more on that [in Apple's documentations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated)